# MongoDB remove duplicated documents

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

I have collection of documents created by importing excel file from accounting using python script and pandas:

```
data = pd.read_excel(fileName, header=0, na_values='') #read the excel file with headers in first row

collection.insert_many(pd.DataFrame.to_dict(data, orient='records')) #insert data to database collection as one row per document with column header as key and cell value as value
```

Single document in collection is single position on invoice and look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596f54f63c25b40b60e8e740"),
    "kod kontrahenta" : "MAXIMA",
    "nazwa kontrahenta" : "KALINOWSKI RAFAŁ \"Przedsiebiorstwo MAXIMA\"",
    "numer faktury" : "001/07/17/FVS",
    "data sprzedaży" : ISODate("2017-07-03T00:00:00Z"),
    "data wystawienia" : ISODate("2017-07-04T00:00:00Z"),
    "termin płatności" : ISODate("2017-10-02T00:00:00Z"),
    "kod towaru" : 30020520,
    "nazwa towaru" : "NIBOPREN N726 BOSTIK TIN 4,5 KG",
    "ilość sprzedana" : 5,
    "jm" : "szt",
    "cena sprzedaży" : 110.25,
    "wartość sprzedaży" : 551.25,
    "dokument wydania" : "0004/7/17/WZ",
    "ilość wydana" : 5,
    "koszt jednostkowy" : 59.69199999999999,
    "koszt ogółem" : 298.46,
    "marża" : 84.69811700060312,
    "rabat %" : 0,
    "Rodzaj kontrahenta" : "Danuta Kamińska",
    "Masa intrastat" : 4.5,
    "Wartość z KWM" : NaN,
    "Masa sprzedana" : 22.5,
    "Grupowanie CC" : "Softflooring"
}
```

Accounting is exporting data from certain timeframe and this data has to be added to collection. It might happen that accounting will export part of data twice (for example when they want some report to be done in the middle of month and later on will export data of full month after month ends). I'm looking for efficient way to detect if document is already in collection and not to insert it twice as it is critical for reports results.

Comment: is the document your export have some kind of unique id if not you need to go through each document to detect if it is a duplicate which will have horrible performance when you insert (I tried that before)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no column which has unique elements. That's why I'm asking :) with unique element it would be simple.

Comment: Actually I think I've found solution to performance issue (at least as good as it can be): After loading new file to import, check dates range in one of columns with dates [issue date] -> detect min and max date and compare rows with just documents within same date range. What do you think?

Comment: How do you figure out two entries are duplicates? What fields make you sure those are the same?

Comment: All of them will be exactly the same. If invoice was imported to db and then it will be once again in the data dump from accounting I need to check if it is in database already and skip this document.